# How to display thumbnail of image in picture library view?

Tags: 2013, view, picture-library, schema

I have created a view in Picture Library's schema file. I want to display the thumbnail of the image with fields.

My code for view is:

```
<View BaseViewID="13" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="Custom Thumbnail" TabularView="TRUE" DefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" Url="Forms/Thumbnails1.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/plicon.png?rev=23">
    <JSLink>SP.UI.TileView.js|callout.js</JSLink>
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Thumbnail"/>
      <FieldRef Name="ImageWidth" />
      <FieldRef Name="ImageHeight" />
      <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" />
      <FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl" />
      <FieldRef Name="Description" />
      <FieldRef ID="{96B83E27-8364-41F6-846B-DF6DBDB6D22E}" Name="oiplbCategory"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{7B0A2603-E100-4856-A58A-251EDF22CBBC}" Name="oiplbBrand"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{8D4BAE9C-6A0F-4805-A910-8B5973F64769}" Name="oiplbBusinessArea"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{A8E2B4E7-0422-428F-99C8-B1FF3ABE5B1F}" Name="oiplbResolution"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{FF551562-7DB4-46CE-857D-BBC6E7574EF9}" Name="oiplbSearchAlias"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef">
        </FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,nopicturesinview_clickupload)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,nopicturesinview_clickupload_howto)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
</View>
```

The column is displayed but after uploading the image it displays blank image instead of small image version of uploaded image. What should I do?

Comment: Where have you found this field "Thumbnail"? In my picture libraries the closest column I can find is "ThumbnailOnForm"

Comment: In the `<Views></Views>` there is first view definition with base view id=0 . In that view there `<FieldRef Name='Thumbnail'/>` is given.

Comment: Ah okey, is there a reasoen why you have two "<JSLink>" nodes?

Comment: No sir, actually I don't know about the JSLink 2 times but there is also 2 jslink nodes in built in Thumbnails view in schema

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't add these properties to `<List>` in `Schema.xml`:

```
ThumbnailSize="160" 
WebImageWidth="640" 
WebImageHeight="480"
```

And these fields to View:

```
<FieldRef Name="DocIcon" />
<FieldRef Name="PreviewOnForm" Explicit="TRUE" />
```

Without them the thumbnails aren't shown.